# modify input allow_error_count in magento import

Tags: import, backend, csv, validation, input

I'm new to magento development and I find myself able to modify the allow_error_count input by backend when making an import. Some clue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change "allow_error_count" input value while you are importing data.

This is the limit which will stop checking file after number of error will be found from your import file.

Ex: In in your import CSV file products SKU's are not exist and we set limit as 10 the system will found if 10 SKU's did not matched while checking import file then it will stop and show an error message.

[image]